# How to customize the uninstall dialog in Programs and Features

Tags: wix

I am working on a Wix project that need to ask users if they want to drop the database when uninstalling. I added the dialog and control in UI for the Wix project. When I click on the MSI the customized dialog for uninstall shows up but it doesn't when I click on it through Uninstall from Programs and Features.

What I need to do to have the same customized uninstall dialog show up from the Programs and Features Uninstall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Uninstall button doesn't show a MSI's UI. So your only option to control the uninstallation UI is to suppress the Uninstall button by setting [ARPNOREMOVE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa367591.aspx), and thus require the user to launch maintenance.

Comment: Yes, this way it forces the maintenance page to display. However it also disables the Remove button. So we need to redefine the maintenance dialog. See [link here](http://devdare.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-force-gui-uninstall-using.html).

Comment: Yeah, you're fighting against MSI here. Note that it you want to prevent a knowledgeable user from uninstalling this way (progress only), you'll have to detect and block it. But that prevents silent uninstalls, so I don't recommend it.

Comment: ARP makes no assumption that it is launching a Windows Installer servicing program (msiexec); Msiexec doesn't care that it was launched via ARP. Windows Installer creates the key in hopes that it is useful. If you don't like the one it creates by default, you _could_ hide it and add your own entire key and set of values. That's a lot of work for a just a different UninstallString.

Comment: @Tom: Half agreed. Your point is valid, but ARP _does_ know that it's a Windows Installer package, and will not respect updates to the main key's UninstallString.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, there is a nice feature you can use through a custom action that tells the session to display a variety of dialog types:

```
Record record = new Record();
record.FormatString = string.Format("Would you like to remove program-generated data?");

MessageResult value = session.Message(InstallMessage.User | (InstallMessage)MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, record);

if (value == MessageResult.Yes)
{
     // Remove program-generated data
}
```

See here for where I came up with this solution: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/UI-on-uninstall-td7593560.html#a7593572

See here for the variety of dialogs you can provide: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371672(v=vs.85).aspx

To use this custom action only on uninstall, schedule it like so:

```
<CustomAction Id="ShowDialog" BinaryKey='CustomActionsBinary' DllEntry='ShowDialogRemoveFiles' 
              Execute='immediate' Return='check' Impersonate='no'/>

<Binary Id='CustomActionsBinary' SourceFile='CustomActions.CA.dll'/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='ShowDialog' Before='InstallFinalize'>REMOVE</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```